# Javascript delay/resizing

Tags: javascript, html, animation, delay

Hi i want to shrink and image and then resize it while keeping it in the same place(centerd in the page) i would like to do this using javascript. I want this to happen on a onclick event. If you need to see my code its here http://cannonmc.net/ .

For more of an idea of what i want/need look at http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/ i want to do the same to my image as what happens when you hover/click on that cookie :).

Thanks

Luke.

Comment: This is a problem i trying to work out how to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a very simple example for you, I hope this helps.

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');

image.onmousedown = function() {
    image.style.width = "47%";
};
image.onmouseup = function() {
    image.style.width = "";
}
```

Would be all JavaScript needed, with the additional CSS. 
Working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zy96xqc7/2/

Comment: Ahh thank you very much this is exactly what i wanted!

Comment: No problem! Would you be so kind as accepting this as the answer and giving it a +1 rating as well. Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: Found out how but i dont have enough reputation points yet, sorry when i get enough ill be sure to come back and give it a +1. Also quick thing i've added it all correct i believe but it doesn't seem to be working, little help? If you just check my website it should be all on there http://cannonmc.net/ .

Comment: Seem to have got it working but its only working from internal styling and scripts also how would i go about keep all the other elements were they are it (The buttons below the face) . I've tried postion: fixed; is this not what i need?